# PHP Array to MySQL, bad things happend with json_encode

Tags: php, mysql, xml, arrays, json

I am looking for solution with one problem.

At this moment I save array to mysql using json_encode and json_decode on output but I have many problems with UTF-8 (bad behaviour with © for example), with paths saved in this array (problem with slashes), problem with /rn etc.

I am looking for other option to save array in Mysql or **safe** mechanism to do this with json_encode without problems with UTF-8, blank spaces etc.

Currently I use:

```
$options[$key] = preg_replace("!([\b\t\n\r\f\"\\'])!", "\\\\\\1", $options[$key]);
```

But it doesn't help me with all the problems...

I was also wondering to save the settings in a file such as XML but first I would prefer to know if there is a "perfect way" to problems with json_encode

To be clear my array contains: paths to files, html and sometimes custom CSS

Comment: Please post the code for your insert. The easiest way to make sure things aren't getting messed up is by using parameterized queries.

Comment: What @Mike said. Properly escaping data for insert can be very tricky. Prepared statements with parameters will avoid all those problems (and are safer).

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like there is no shortcuts in this topic. I will create something like "prepareArrayValues" function and if I still had problems I get back to you guys.

Thank you.

Comment: @KrystianPodemski they just told you how to shortcut your problem by using prepared statement you're just over-complicating it. In addition if you're having UTF8 issues then there is more to it to check a few things like how you're initiating your connection to the database and what encoding the tables were created with. If your json breaks half way it could be a field size/type issue.